# Finding Max and Min of a Sextic Function

Tags: calculus

Given the function $f(x) = x^6+2x^5-3x^4+2x^3-3x^2+8x-2$ how do you find it's max and min?

When you take the first derivative, you end up with a complete Quintic function, you cannot solve that without graphing. When you take the second derivative, you still have a Quartic function to deal with. So is it possible to find the max and min of this equation by hand?

Comment: is is an equation or a function?

Comment: oh yea.. sorry I meant to say function...

Comment: best plan would be to turn it into form like (x-a_0)(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_5)

Comment: @tp1 Hmm.. but what if it is not factorable

Comment: well, then you need numerical methods like root-finding algorithms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the problem is very difficult without graphing. With graphing, what you would notice is that the first derivative cancels only once in the real domain. This means that the minimum is unique. What you have to do is first to solve $$g(x)=f'(x)=6 x^5+10 x^4-12 x^3+6 x^2-6 x+8$$ So, use Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}$$ In your case, the iterative scheme will then be (after minor simplifications) $$x_{n+1}=\frac{12 x_n^5+15 x_n^4-12 x_n^3+3 x_n^2-4}{15 x_n^4+20 x_n^3-18 x_n^2+6 x_n-3}$$ Since you can observe it from the graph and since I am lazy, let us start using $x_0=-3$. Then, Newton method will generate the following iterates $$x_1=-2.75203$$ $$x_2=-2.65910$$ $$x_3=-2.64657$$ $$x_4=-2.64636$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Now, "just" plug this number in $f(x)$ to get the value at the minimum.

**Edit**

You could be interested knowing that there are methods of higher order than Newton (order $2$) : for example,  Halley method (order $3$) or Householder method (order $4$) (higher order methods do not have name). So, let us call $x_{(k)}$ the first iterate of method of order $k$. For your problem, you would so get 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & x_{(k)} \\
 2 & -2.75203 \\
 3 & -2.69167 \\
 4 & -2.66860 \\
 5 & -2.65810 \\
 6 & -2.65285 \\
 7 & -2.65007 \\
 8 & -2.64853 \\
 9 & -2.64765
\end{array}
\right)$$ As you can see, starting quite far away from the solution, a single iteration can give a quite good estimate of the solution.

**Edit**

Just for your entertainment (do not worry, you will learn about that sooner or later), just as with Taylor series, functions can be approximated locally by rational expressions (they are called Padé approximants); they write $$f(x)=\frac {P_m(x)}{P_n(x)}$$ where $P_k$ denotes a polynomial of degree $k$.

The simplest one $(m=n=1)$ write around $x=a$ $$f(x)\approx \frac{f(a)+\frac{ 2 f'(a)^2-f(a) f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)}{1-\frac{
   f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)}$$ Applied to $g(x)$ around $x=-3$, this xould give $$g(x) \approx \frac{-244+\frac{30523 }{41}(x+3)}{1+\frac{161 }{164}(x+3)}$$ So, since we want $g(x)=0$ we just need to cancel the numerator and get as an approximation $$x=-\frac{81565}{30523}\approx -2.67225$$ Using $(m=1,n=2)$ would give, still at the price of a linear equation, $$x=-\frac{14175257}{5345720}\approx -2.65170$$ Funny, isn't it ?

Comment: But what about the case where Newton's Method fails ? would we have to use Regula falsi or bisection method as Dr.G suggested?

Comment: @DavidYue. The cases where Newton method fails are well known. You can use any root-finding method of your choice but you will need first to bracket the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $f(x)$ does not have a maximum since the $x^6$ term will dominate the rest. To find the minimum, there is no straightforward method. Your best bet is to employ a numerical method with the help of a computer algebra system such as MAPLE or Mathematica (see e.g. Dr. Graubner's answer -- I believe he is using MAPLE?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's general procedure how to handle these kind of cases: (assuming you did $df/dx=0$ first)

1. First try to turn the polynomial to form $(x-a_0)(x-a_1)...(x-a_n)$ where a_n is the roots of the function.
2. If that doesn't work, one alternative is to approximate your function with a polynomial, and then try step 1 again.
3. If everything else fails, try root-finding-algorithms
4. preimage/inverse image can reveal some properties of your functions.

Comment: You've summarized it quite well, however, I'm not quite sure how you find the inverse without solving for x. Do I just reflect on y=x? How would the inverse graph without the function help with the process?

Comment: No, the inverse image is defined by $f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in X | f(x) \in B \}$, which uses the set-builder notation for it's definition. But basically it's just manually tracking the the fibers in the in function.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the derivative gives you $6x^5+10x^4-12x^3+4x+7=0$ which as you have stated can not be solved for an exact value of $x$. Similarly you can not find an exact value for $y$ as attempting to substitute this isn't the original equation will not eliminate $x$.

$$y=x^6 + 2 x^5 - 3 x^4 + 2 x^2 + 8 x - 2$$

$$=\frac{x}{6}(6x^5+10x^4-12x^3+4x+7) + 2 x^5 - 3 x^4 + 2 x^2 + 8 x - 2 - \frac{x}{6}(10x^4-12x^3+4x+7)$$

$$=0+2 x^5 - 3 x^4 + 2 x^2 + 8 x - 2 - \frac{x}{6}(10x^4-12x^3+4x+7)$$

$$=\frac{x^5}{3}-x^4+\frac{4x^2}{3}+\frac{41x}{6}-2$$

$$=\frac{1}{18}(6x^5+10x^4-12x^3+4x+7)-x^4+\frac{4x^2}{3}+\frac{41x}{6}-2-\frac{1}{18}(10x^4-12x^3+4x+7)$$

$$=0-x^4+\frac{4x^2}{3}+\frac{41x}{6}-2-\frac{1}{18}(10x^4-12x^3+4x+7)$$

$$=-\frac{14x^4}{9}+\frac{2x^3}{3}+\frac{4x^2}{3}+\frac{119x}{18}-\frac{43}{18}$$

And we can see that $y$ still depends upon the numerical value of $x$. So if you have more information (i.e. additional equations/restrictions on $x$) then you could potentially reduce this down to a numerical value even without finding a numerical value of $x$.